# Best Compilers for C#

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

I am starting to learn to program in C# and I was wondering what is currently the best compiler and what IDEs have built-in C# compilers. I am 11 years old and starting to learn to program and need to choose a compiler.

I know about the MS Visual Express ones, but I want to know what are there good and bad things about it.

Also, is there a way that I can download Visual C# Express Offline? I can't use the web installer.

Comment: @SLakes sorry I did not know that can I say both C and C#?

Comment: You will learn that they are 2 completely different languages. Just because `house` sounds like `mouse`, it doesnt mean they have something in common.

Comment: Your tags also include `[C++]`. Are you interested in a C++ compiler too? C++, C and C# are totally different languages. They just happen to have a similar syntax, but the similarities stop there.

Comment: For offline installer, http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-All select the All - Offline Installer

Comment: I can't download anything over 49MB @Martheen could you please split it up and but it somewhere I can download please

Comment: This is a little ridiculous. Do you want to learn C#, C++, or C? They're different languages, and I don't advise learning theme together. I would recommend C# if you're just getting started; it's a little more straight-forward. Marc Gravell and I have already told you where you can download Visual Studio C# Express, or MonoDevelop. See those comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842047/learning-c-as-a-start). This is another question that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Benny : Is it the limitation of your ISP, or you're using a cyber cafe to access the internet? I suggest you just find nearest college with computer science, they should have it.

Comment: @Martheen I don't have enogh data on my plan and I use my liberie and I can't run .exe files there and they have an 49MB download limt.

Comment: @Benny, I'm sorry to say, but you may have to wait until you have better access to the internet to start compiling C# programs. Alternatively, you can try to get around your internet problem with a shell account like http://devio.us/ that shell provider is the best I've used and provide a full set of (C and C++) compiler tools and reasonable quotas. So maybe you can at least learn C or C++ while you wait for better internet to learn C#. (I'm assuming this is your first programming language)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like your question is more like, "which IDE should I learn with?".

I would suggest MS Express editions for C, C++, and C#. It's high quality, free, has an intuitive interface, and has a very large community for support.

Comment: For C/C++ VS 2008 (not 2010!).For C# VS 2010. For C/C++ you can also check Netbeans IDE which uses gcc as a compiler(AFAIR).

Comment: @kubal5003: Why do you say that? (referring to your insistence not to use vs2010 for C and C++)

Comment: @kubal5003: In my experience, VS2010 has significantly better support for programming in C++...it is closer to standards compliance (including lots of C++0x stuff) and the error messages are generally more helpful.

Comment: Note that programs created using the express editions of Visual Studio have no licensing restrictions. That is, you can make commercial products with the express editions. They use the same compilers found in the non-free visual studio editions.

Comment: @Travis
"In my experience, VS2010 has significantly better support for programming in C++"
Yes, you're right. I discovered today that pure C++ has all the support in VS 2010, however C++/CLI doesn't which is why I wrote about 2008 not 2010. I just wasn't aware of the difference.

Comment: One thing that should be taken into account is that with Visual Studio Express, developers may not be able to release their programs to the public because of the user agreement. That's the problem I had with VC++, so I never used it.

Answer (score 2):

### C# / .NET

[Visual C# Express 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) should give you everything you need to learn to program in C#.

If you really want to learn, especially on your own, you'll need interesting projects.

I don't think you should overlook doing some Windows Phone 7 Development to get familiar with the language and libraries in a fairly constrained environment.

If your high school allows it, see if you can set yourself up on DreamSpark.com and get yourself the XNA stuff, which (last time I checked) included a free membership that will allow you to develop stuff for the Xbox 360.

Microsoft's Coding4Fun blog might also be inspiring, although it seems to me that a lot of the projects are so esoteric that they probably won't teach very much, nor will they be interesting unless you have that specific piece of hardware.

### C

Learning C is probably best done on a Unix-like environment as this is where the language has its origins. A modern GNU/Linux distribution will give you everything you need (you may have to install the development packages yourself) which is basically:

1. a text editor (choose one; many like Emacs, Vim and Scite)
2. a C compiler (GCC)
3. a debugger (GDB)

Any distribution should have packages for these available.

### Challenges

Try solving the problems from Project Euler in whatever languages you are trying to learn. Solving these will help you think analytically as well as teach you language constructs and certain library features. Ask your mathematics teacher for help if you are stuck with the maths side of those problems.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

I have found [Compilr](http://compilr.com) which is a online IDE and is free for 3 projects and includes a number of langues.

Answer (score 1):

My sugestion is [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)):

> Mono is a free and open source project led by Xamarin (formerly by Novell and originally by Ximian) to create an Ecma standard-compliant, .NET Framework-compatible set of tools including, among others, a C# compiler and a Common Language Runtime.
>
> The stated purpose of Mono is not only to be able to run Microsoft .NET applications cross-platform, but also to bring better development tools to Linux developers.[4] Mono can be run on many software systems including Android, most Linux distributions, BSD, OS X, Windows, Solaris, and even some game consoles such as PlayStation 3, Wii, and Xbox 360.
>
> The logo of Mono is a stylized monkey's face, mono being Spanish for monkey.

Answer (score 0):

for c definitely go for ICC
C# I might guess you go for VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

I would say get yourself a copy of linux and gcc. Ubuntu is a nice way to get going.

Comment: What IDE does Ubuntu bundle - is it any good?

Comment: It doesn't bundle an IDE, and that's exactly the benefit. Using IDE's when you're still learning is not a good way to learn, instead write code using the terminal and say gedit (comes default), then, once you get better, you can get a proper IDE. There are many devs who despite programming for 10 years, still use gedit and a terminal window. For C#, there's monodevelop. Also, for learning C, make sure you get K&R (its a book)

Comment: sorry I can't use Ubuntu at the momment :(

Comment: VirtualBox maybe? Believe me, its worth the initial effort :)

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about three different languages. C++ is an expanded version of C and although it is its own language completely, C++ compilers can also compile C code.

If you're looking to learn programming I recommend C# and Visual C# 2010 Express edition.